# Removing only alpha duplicates

Tags: python, python-2.7, duplicates, alphanumeric

In Python, I would like to remove duplicate letters from a string, but not numbers or spaces. I came up with:

```
result = []
seen = set()
for char in string:
    if char not in seen:
        seen.add(char)
        result.append(char)
return "".join(result)
```

But that makes:

```
>>> delete_duplicate_letters("13 men were wounded in an explosion yesterday around 3:00pm.")
13 menwroudiaxplsyt:0.
```

When I want:

```
>>> delete_duplicate_letters("13 men were wounded in an explosion yesterday around 3:00pm.")
13 men wr oud i a xpls yt 3:00.
```

I've tried to use `letter` instead of `char`, the `isalpha()` function and `if int` statements etc but I couldn't get anything to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
result = ""
for char in string:
    if not (char.isalpha() and char in result):
        result += char
```

Comment: +1 for a nice simple solution, just hope the string doesn't get really big or the quadratic runtime will kick in

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> from string import digits, whitespace
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> s = set(whitespace + digits)
>>> ''.join(OrderedDict((object() if c in s else c, c) for c in text).values())
'12 men wr oud i a xpls yt  3:00.'
```

`object()` here is just used to make sure the keys for characters you want to leave are *always unique* since `object()` creates a different object each time. The other characters are used as the keys themselves so duplicates are filtered.

Comment: This deserves like a bajillion up votes. It looks so... awesome

Answer (score 1):

use `str.isspace` and `str.isdigit`:

```
strs = "13 men were wounded in an explosion yesterday around 3:00pm."
result = []
seen = set()
for char in strs:
    if char not in seen:
        if not (char.isspace() or char.isdigit()):
           seen.add(char)
        result.append(char)
print "".join(result)
```

**output:**

```
13 men wr oud i a xpls yt  3:00.
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're almost there. You can just add some checks in the loop:

```
result = []
seen = set()
for char in string:
    if char.isdigit() or char.isspace():
        result.append(char)
    elif char not in seen:
        seen.add(char)
        result.append(char)
return "".join(result)
```

Comment: +1 Good solution but this produces an extra space since `around` is fully removed

Comment: @NiklasHansson See OP's update: multiple digits should be preserved.

Comment: My bad, he altered his example.